Unable to fetch NEXT_PUBLIC_OPENAI_API_KEY in Vercel production environment
I'm experiencing an issue with accessing an environment variable in a Next.js project deployed on Vercel. The variable is correctly set in both my local environment and the Vercel dashboard, but it's not accessible in the production environment.
Project Setup:

Next.js project using OpenAI API
Environment variable: NEXT_PUBLIC_OPENAI_API_KEY
Correctly set in .env.local file locally
Set in Vercel dashboard (confirmed)

Issue:
In production, process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_OPENAI_API_KEY is returning an empty string.
Code:
const prompt = generatePrompt(scores);
console.log(prompt);
console.log("calling openAI");
let apiKey: string = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_OPENAI_API_KEY ?? "";
console.log('Using API Key:', apiKey); // Logs empty string in production

const response = await fetch('https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions', {
  // ... API call configuration
});

Workaround:
If I hardcode the API key, it works:
if (apiKey === "") {
  console.log("hardcoding api key");
  apiKey = "sk-..."; // Hardcoded API key
}

What I've Tried:

Deleted and re-added the environment variable in the Vercel dashboard
Confirmed the variable is correctly set in the Vercel project settings
Verified the variable works correctly in local development

Question:
Why is process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_OPENAI_API_KEY empty in the Vercel production environment, and how can I resolve this issue?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Make sure that you checked production for the env variable in vercel and then redeployed your app after you added it.

Thanks! I did; I even renamed it, but no luck...
